# Visual studio 2015 Parentheses silly highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Just installed visual studio 2015 and I was shocked by this terrible parentheses highlighting system.
[image]

Is there any way I can turn off that parentheses highlighting system? Or lower the brightness of it?

Regards, Tuukka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this setting to any color you want. Also you see more introduction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/be94e8aw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

[image]